# How to change CSS of a website depending on whether it is being viewed on mobile or computer?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website but I have two stylesheets, one for computers and other for mobile.

I want that if a user is using mobile to view the website, the CSS for mobile be used and if the website is being viewed from desktop, the CSS for desktop be used.

Is there any way to detect the browser(mobile or computer) and use the CSS accordingly?

I can detect the browser using javascript but cannot change the CSS.

Comment: Why the -1? I think this is not a bad question, although a search might have been good.

Comment: You need to use google for this, and in short, you can either use media queries or if you are js fan, than you can use `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Its the screen size that matters for css in mob and desktop. Use mediaquery as in my answer and resize your browser(computer). So, works both for mob&desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good to use Media query. eg:-

```
<!-- Phone -->
<link href="phon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:320px)">
<!-- Tablet -->
<link href="tab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px)">
<!-- Desktop -->
<link href="pc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:769px)">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the CSS [media element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to use conditional CSS.  It's not exactly a browser query, but using screen sizes if you want:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 765px){ /*..*/ }
```

Or

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
 /* some css here */
}
```

There are a lot of great tips on this site:  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml